Rsync (via Cron) is pulling from local media server torrent directory - what happens with partial or missing files?
My public media server (debian 11) server1 /home/TV/... copies TV shows via cron and rsync from private media/torrent server (debian 12) server2 /home/TV/ every hour:
rsync --update --omit-dir-times --no-perms -av 192.168.1.153:/home/TV/ /home/TV

The torrent application sets the time to modified at download completion and at download start.

What happens when a TV file in server2 happens to be downloading as server1 attempts to copy?

My debian 12 is having lockup problems about every 3 days so I reboot at midnight and what happens when rsync attempts to copy from a down server?



Thank you for commenting. - The torrent application sets the time to modified at download completion and at download start (I will check). I -rsync --update --omit-dir-times --no-perms -av 192.168.1.153:/home/TV/ /home/TV - so ssh copy I think.

from stat on torrent download completed - atime - 8:39:22 , mtime - 8:39:19, ctime - 8:39:20, btime 8:34:56  - So creation time is at start of download & completion is at completion of download.



What happens when a TV file in server2 happens to be downloading as server1 attempts to copy?


At worst, the rsync tool will copy what it sees. Fortunately because you're using a network copy, only the blocks that have been changed since the last copy will be transferred.
If the torrent tool only updates the modification time (mtime) at completion rsync may not even attempt to copy a partial file, as it shortcuts work by looking at the file size and modification time.


What happens when rsync attempts to copy from a down server?


It will wait, quite possibly forever. You might want to add a timeout flag.
Here is a suggested command line. I've defined a 10 minute timeout (for any copy, not just for unavailable hosts) and downgraded --archive (-a) to -rt (--recursive --times). The --no-perms flag would have been overridden by your later use of -a.
rsync -rtv --update --partial --inplace --omit-dir-times --timeout=600 192.168.1.153:/home/TV/ /home/TV

